# CCD Problem section Validation Problem

Tags: hl7, ccd

I am getting following error in ENTRY of my Problems section when validated through online MDHT tool or from API:

> /clinicalDocument[1]/component[1]/structuredBody[1]/component[1]/section[1]/entry[1]/act[1]/entryRelationship[1]/observation[1]/entryRelationship[1]/observation[1]
>   org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.ccd  error   CCD Status Observation
>   Target of an entryRelationship whose value for "entryRelationship /
>   @typeCode" SHALL be "REFR" 2.16.840.1.113883.5.1002
>   ActRelationshipType STATIC. (CONF-509)

My Problem entry looks like:

```
<entry typeCode="DRIV">
            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
              <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.27"/>
              <id root="d828b5a4-3ab6-44ed-8ee9-4ad879fe5b91"/>
              <code nullFlavor="NA"/>
              <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.28"/>
                  <id root="f2d23742-2672-4f08-b523-abe26e1a8102"/>
                  <code code="ASSERTION" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.4"/>
                  <statusCode code="completed"/>
                  <effectiveTime>
                    <low value="20061005"/>
                  </effectiveTime>
                  <value xsi:type="CD" code="NA" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Abuse Issues - Victim"/>
                  <entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">
                    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                      <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.50"/>
                      <code code="33999-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Status"/>
                      <statusCode code="completed"/>
                      <value xsi:type="CE" code="55561003" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" displayName="Active"/>
                    </observation>
                  </entryRelationship>
                </observation>
              </entryRelationship>
            </act>
          </entry>
```

When validated through NIST tool it says document is valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but this came up in a search and I can help.

Change this:
`<entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">`

To this:
`<entryRelationship typeCode="REFR">`

It should validate.